# AJAX not redirecting to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to clone a particular div inside an html file through AJAX and then to a PHP file that would create a new html file with the newly cloned content and save the save it in a temp directory.

My ultimate goal to generate this temp file that I would extract its url and email it to a client. Eventually (after X amount of days), the file would be deleted.

But this is still thinking way ahead... the issue I am running into is that when i click the SEND button, it seems to cycle through the AJAX ok, but doesn't seem to ever hit the PHP file. Here is what I have so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#send").click( function() {
      var extract = $("#extract").html();
     $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : "php.php",
          data : {id : extract},
          success: function(data){
             console.log("ok");
          }
       });
   });

});
```

```css
p, h1, img {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extract">
   <h1>Header Content</h1>
   <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet shank pig filet mignon, pastrami hamburger andouille tenderloin sausage.</p>
   <p>Flank cupim ribeye beef ribs shoulder. Beef cow frankfurter ball tip capicola turducken porchetta tenderloin pork loin picanha turkey fatback pork.</p>
   <p><img src="http://www.placecage.com/300/450" alt=""></p>
   <p>Swine tri-tip porchetta pig filet mignon picanha ham hock turkey burgdoggen strip steak flank turducken. Sirloin venison andouille kevin ball tip. </p>
</div>
<button type="button" name="button" id="send">SEND</button>
```

In my my php.php file (it lives in the directory level as the js file), I simply have an echo "ok"; and not happens on the screen. I get the console log, but no echo. What am I missing?

Thank you,

Sergio

Comment: The behaviour you describe looks correct for the code you've shown. What's the code in the PHP file? What are you expecting to have happen?

Comment: You don't do anything with the data received back from the server inside your JS success handler.

Comment: thanks guys, yes I don't have any php code in the php file yet except a simple echo just to make sure everything is connect and running.

Comment: `(it lives in the directory level as the js file)`, wrong ist MUST be in the folder where (HTML code) file is.

Comment: which is also in the same level as the js and php. should of craified that.

Comment: ajax is meant to avoid redirect. If you want to redirect, then why you go for ajax?

Comment: The do a simple `echo 'foobar';` in php.php and do `console.log(data);` and see if foobar comes in. Else do press F12 in the browser to watch and check what happens when you hit the button [network tab].

Comment: could be something with the placement of the php file

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions, yes that worked, duhhh. thanks.

Comment: as arkascha said - he didn't do anything with the returned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#send").click( function() {
      var extract = $("#extract").html();
     $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : "FULL_PATH_OF_PHP_FILE_php.php",
          data : {id : extract},
          success: function(data){
             console.log("ok");
             console.log (data);
          }
       });
   });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some basic information about server side and front side.

Take a look and read more about it here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Also Like @arkascha said you are not doing anything with what you receive from the server.

Basically your JS will send a HTTP Request to the server (POST|GET), in your case seems to be POST, with the id (whatever you define in `data`).

The tricky is your success function, `success: function(data)` this data will be the response from the server. Since you just echoed, data should be a string type variable.

Next steps would be from your php script do something like this (i am sending a JSON response which is what happens most of the time so you can parse it easily on the javascript / client side)

```
echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
```

then structure your Ajax call to accept json (you can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

`dataType: 'JSON'`

Then your success function can be something like:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data); // prints an array

    if (data.success) {
        // show some success information
    }
}
```